# Hiding borders on specific lines of table, HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get rid of the border in specific rows on this table. I want a border around the rows for Men and the brand Armada but to not have the middle botder lines. For some reason I can't get rid of it using the tr class. What is the mistake I'm making?

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noBorder {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th>Men</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Waist</th>
    <th>Lengths</th>
    <th>Quick Description </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th>Armada</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Armada</td>
    <td>Tracer 88</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>162, 172</td>
    <td>Cut with an 88mm waist width and Armada s snow-shedding Tapertop topsheet to minimize added weight from snow buildup, the Armada Tracer 88 Skis travel swiftly and efficiently uphill while the EST All-Mtn Rocker provides versatile performance on the
      journey down.</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying border to `tr` and `th/td`. So removing border from `tr` is not enough. You need also to remove it from `th/td` so you may adjust your CSS like this  :

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noBorder {
  border: 0;
}

.noBorder th,
.noBorder td {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th>Men</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Waist</th>
    <th>Lengths</th>
    <th>Quick Description </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th>Armada</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Armada</td>
    <td>Tracer 88</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>162, 172</td>
    <td>Cut with an 88mm waist width and Armada s snow-shedding Tapertop topsheet to minimize added weight from snow buildup, the Armada Tracer 88 Skis travel swiftly and efficiently uphill while the EST All-Mtn Rocker provides versatile performance on the
      journey down.</td>
  </tr>
```

another solution is to use `colspan` to avoid adding empty cells  :

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noBorder {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th colspan=5>Men</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Waist</th>
    <th>Lengths</th>
    <th>Quick Description </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <th colspan=5>Armada</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Armada</td>
    <td>Tracer 88</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>162, 172</td>
    <td>Cut with an 88mm waist width and Armada s snow-shedding Tapertop topsheet to minimize added weight from snow buildup, the Armada Tracer 88 Skis travel swiftly and efficiently uphill while the EST All-Mtn Rocker provides versatile performance on the
      journey down.</td>
  </tr>
```